# How does indexing a list with a tuple work?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I am learning Python and came across this example:

```
W = ((0,1,2),(3,4,5),(0,4,8),(2,4,6))
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
for row in W:
    print b[row[0]], b[row[1]], b[row[2]]
```

which prints:

a b c

d e f

a e i

c e g

I am trying to figure out why!

I get that for example the first time thru the expanded version is:

```
print b[(0,1,2)[0]], b[(0,1,2)[1]], b[(0,1,2)[2]]
```

But I don't understand how the (0,1,2) is interacting.  Can anyone offer an explanation?  Thanks.

(this is an abbreviated version of some code for a tic tac toe game, and it works well, I just don't get this part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it iterates over a tuple of tuples, each `row` is a three-element tuple, when printing it accesses three elements of the `b` list by index, which is what `row` tuple contains.

probably, a slightly less cluttered way to do this is:

```
for f, s, t in W:
    print b[f], b[s], b[t]
```

Comment: I figured it out from another post, but I like your post because your suggested way is a little clearer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In shot, the `(0,1,2)` does nothing. Its a tuple and can be indexed just like a list, so `b[(0,1,2)[0]]` becomes `b[0]` since `(0,1,2)[0] == 0`.

In the first step Python does `b[row[0]]` → `b[(0,1,2)[0]]` → `b[0]` → `'a'`

Btw, to get multiple items from a sequence at once you can use a operator:

```
from operator import itemgetter
for row in W:
    print itemgetter(*row)(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing a tuple just extracts the nth element, just as when indexing an array. That is, the expanded version

```
print b[(0,1,2)[0]], b[(0,1,2)[1]], b[(0,1,2)[2]]
```

is equal to

```
print b[0], b[1], b[2]
```

IE, the 0th element of the (0, 1, 2) tuple (`(0, 1, 2)[0]`) is 0.

Comment: This helped.  I was stuck on the b[...] part and was missing that the (0,1,2)[0] part was an operation in itself - ie indexing a tuple.  Then I tried just that part, with different variations, in the shell and saw what was being returned, then I got it!  thank.

Answer (score 0):

`for row in W:`

first tuple placed into `row` is `(0,1,2)`

in other words, `W[0] == (0,1,2)`

```
Therefore, since `row` == (0,1,2), then row[0] == 0
```

So the `[0]th element of b == 'a'`

```
b[0] == 'a'
```

and so on...

```
b[1] == 'b'
b[2] == 'c'
```

Comment: This is confusing: "`row[0] == (0,1,2)` Therefore, `row[0] == 0`"

Answer (score 0):

Try to write down the values of all variables in each step: the result you get is right.

interaction 1:

- row is (0,1,2)
- *b[row[0]], b[row[1]], b[row[2]]* is b[(0,1,2)[0], (0,1,2)[1], (0,1,2)[2]], == b[0], b[1], b[2]

interaction 2:

- *row* is (3,4,5)
- *b[row[0]], b[row[1]], b[row[2]]* is b[3], b[4], b[5]

Answer (score 0):

A Python interactive shell will help you see what is going on:

```
In [78]: W = ((0,1,2),(3,4,5),(0,4,8),(2,4,6))

In [79]: b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

In [81]: row=W[0]       # The first time throught the for-loop, row equals W[0]

In [82]: row
Out[82]: (0, 1, 2)

In [83]: row[0]
Out[83]: 0

In [84]: b[row[0]]
Out[84]: 'a'

In [85]: b[row[1]]
Out[85]: 'b'

In [86]: b[row[2]]
Out[86]: 'c'
```